# how to execute shell command files in python

Tags: python

I am having trouble executing the following shell command.  I'm in windows 10.  I had to delete the user authorization here and left it as 'tktk' as i dind't want my authorization out here like that.

```
curl 'https://pegasus-test.etflogic.io/portfolio/analyze' -H 'authority: pegasus-test.etflogic.io' -H 'pragma: no-cache' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'authorization: tktk' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'origin: https://akita.etflogic.com' -H 'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'referer: https://akita.etflogic.com/portfolio-analysis' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --data-binary '{"portfolio":{"currency":"usd","id":"8576e266-c6f4-44fe-a6a6-9c64869b55dd","name":"test1","records":[{"locale":"US","id":"df92931e-3063-4889-8e4b-100c66f14d22","name":"SSGA SPDR S&P 500 - SSgA Active Trust","secid":549535,"size":100,"ticker":"SPY US"}],"size_type":"notional","type":"primary"}}' --compressed > /tmp/jsonpayload
```

I stored the above command in a test.sh file
I'm having trouble executing the above shell command.  It works on the linux terminal.  But it doesn't work on my windows cmd.  I need to read the above url, get the json object and do some analysis with it.

What i tried:

```
import subprocess 
ans = subprocess.Popen(["bash",os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test.sh')])
```

This fails.  ok...

I tried then...

```
subprocess.call(['test.sh'])
```

I'm getting error '%1 is not a valid Win32 application'

Comment: Why don't you use Python's `requests` module instead of `curl`?

Comment: Probably because `curl` doesn't come with windows by default. Did you try installing `curl` for windows?

Comment: yea I did.  but it doesn't work still

Comment: Before calling the shell command from python, I would recommend to try to call it from `cmd` or the Powershell. Did you get "not a valid Win32 application" for both tries ?

Comment: _This fails._ Fails how? _I'm getting error '%1 is not a valid Win32 application'_ Is that the entire error message?

Answer (score 1):

I copied your `test.sh` code into my own `test.sh` file, and tested a few different things.

Try using `os.system` for calling your command instead of methods from `subprocess`.

This worked for me:

```
import os
os.system(os.getcwd() + '/test.sh')
```

If you prefer `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test.sh')` instead of what I have here, you can use that too, there's no major difference.

I hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: I’m not at work atm.  When I get back tomorrow morning, I will check this.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
# Importing the necessary packages
$ from subprocess import call  

# Executing the test.sh script
$ call('sh test.sh 2>/dev/null', shell=True)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.